# 検索 findアクション追加後にshowアクションでActiveRecord::RecordNotFoundエラーが発生する

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

どこのコードが悪くて、idを拾えないのかわかりません。
ご教授お願いいたします。

[image: エラー]
**コントローラー　　people_controller.rb**

```
class PeopleController < ApplicationController
  layout 'people'
def index
  @msg = 'Person data.'
  @data = Person.all
end
def show
  @msg = "Indexe data."
  @data = Person.find(params[:id])
end
def find
  @msg = 'please type search word...'
  @people = Array.new
  if request.post? then
    obj = Person.find params['find']
    @people.push obj
  end
end
```

**ビュー　　show.html.erb**

```
<h1>People#index</h1>
<p>
    <%= @msg %>
</p>
<pre>
<table>
  <tr><th>Id</th>
    <td><%= @data.id %></td></tr>
  <tr><th>Name</th>
    <td><%= @data.name %></td></tr>
  <tr><th>Age</th>
    <td><%= @data.age %></td></tr>
  <tr><th>Mail</th>
    <td><%= @data.mail %></td></tr>
</table>
</pre>
```

**ビュー　　find.html.erb**

```
<h1>People#Find</h1>
<p>
    <%= @msg %>
</p>
<table>
  <%= form_tag(controller: "people", action: "find") do %>
  <tr><th>FIND</th>
    <td><%= text_field_tag("find") %></td>
  <tr>
    <td><%= submit_tag("Click") %></td>
  </tr>
 <% end %>
</table>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Id</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Age</th>
    <th>Mail</th>
  </tr>
  <% @people.each do |obj| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= obj.id %></td>
      <td><%= obj.name %></td>
      <td><%= obj.age %></td>
      <td><%= obj.mail %></td>
    </tr>
   <% end %>
 </table>
```

**ルート　　routes.rb**

```
get 'people/:id', to: 'people#show'
get 'people/find', to: 'people#find'
post 'people/find', to: 'people#find'
```

**データベース　　db < migrate < hoge_create_people.rb**

```
class CreatePeople < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :people do |t|
      t.text :name
      t.integer :age
      t.text :mail

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

**ビューのキャプチャ**

[image: 一覧]

Answer (score 1):

エラー情報に

```
app/controllers/people_controller.rb:11:in `show'
```

および

```
Parameters

{"id" => "find"}
```

とありますね。

ルーティング規則は上から見ていって最初にリクエストにマッチしたものが使われるので、

```
get 'people/:id', to: 'people#show'
get 'people/find', to: 'people#find'
```

の順で書くと、 `/people/find` は `people/:id` を `:id` => `"find"` というパラメータで呼び出したと解釈され、 `show` アクションにルーティングされます。

Comment: sakuroさん非常にわかりやすい回答ありがとうございます！！！